# Can we change data directory for single table or database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can we change data directory for single table or database in postgresql.
Actually my requirement is that I want to keep all tables data in **C** drive but customers table data in **D** drive. how to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a [tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) for the tables outside the data directory.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbsp LOCATION 'D:\customer_tables';
```

Then add `TABLESPACE tbsp` to all `CREATE TABLE` statements that should be on `D`.